# phonegap Facebook integration -getting user details from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, cordova

I'm creating a html5 application using PhoneGap..i want to integrate facebook into my application. what i want to do is,i want the users to login into my application with Facebook, but after authentication i need to get the details of the particular user who has logged-in .eg.profile name,email id,date of birth,place,address,profile pic etc...is there any particular API which provides all these details as response, when we pass the USERNAME AND PASSWORD.please suggest me a way..or tel me if it is possible.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap is just a mobile platform wrapper around HTML/other web formats. So since the tools are easily available to achieve this using them, PhoneGap is no exception. Learn and implement the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), which is Facebook's total solution for integrating FB into your app. Once a user has logged in with the OAuth 2.0 authentication, the Graph API access token allows you to grab all information (within the user's set access rights) required!

Once you're familiar with how the Graph API works, start with the extensive guide to implementing user login [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), and after that grabbing profile information will be simple!

Comment: thanks Andeh for the quick reply..i have gone through Facebook graph API...if we know the id of a particular user then we can get the profile details..is their any way to get the id of the user who has logged in....or can we get the id of the user by sending the Facebook log in username and password

Comment: If I understand your comment fully, then it's possible to get _some_ details just from a user id's profile page, but then you're getting into site-scraping, which is a terrible idea, most profiles are all private anyway, and it's probably against FB's TOS. Either way you're going to need to allow a user to log in so you can then get their profile details... there are deprecated APIs but FB will drop support for them at any time. In the long run it will save you a lot of time/effort to just use the Graph API! Also if iOS, Apple rejects apps without single sign-on. Another reason to use Graph!

Comment: ok....listed below are the options given by the Facebook for authentication ..but i'm using cross platform...so how will i do authentication 1 Authentication in native Android apps
2 Authentication in native iOS apps
3 Authentication within a Page Tab on www.facebook.com
4 Authentication within a Canvas Page on apps.facebook.com
5 Authentication for Websites & Mobile Web apps using Javascript (client-side flow)
6 Authentication for Websites & Mobile Web apps using a Server (server-side flow)
7 Authentication for devices without access to a browser

Comment: You most likely want `5 Authentication for Websites & Mobile Web apps using Javascript (client-side flow)`. It automatically keeps your user logged in on subsequent returns to the app as well.

Comment: Not a problem. If this answer gave you the best solution, mark it as accepted with the green arrow tick button! Unless a more direct solution to your problem comes along, but I'm positive the Graph API is your ideal solution.

Comment: hi Andeh....i have tried with what you have said.....but not working...when i go-ogled i got a Facebook integration using phonegap.... i tried the code..the code is running...no force close...but nothing is being displayed....i have provided the url below..can u plz check it out http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88#comment-1333

Comment: That test project works fine for me, presents the ChildBrowser plugin. You have to change the values in `www/js/init.js` to your username and password for a hardcoded login! Also verify your version of PhoneGap, that project is only guaranteed to work 100% on PhoneGap 1.3 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your skills lie in the Javascript/HTML realm so [here is a link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) that will tell you all you need to know about using javascript to access the facebook apis.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Facebook for Websites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web) and the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) guide. Facebook also have a [JavaScript Test Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console) which allows you to test and debug JavaScript SDK methods.
For example usage:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

A sample plugin project that can you refer [Facebook for PhoneGap on Android](https://github.com/jos3000/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

phonegap Facebook integration -getting user details from Facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/